# Display certain properties of array members in Unity editor depending on other properties of those array members

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have a class `MyClass` which has enum and properties. Depending on the enumeration, I want to display certain properties in the editor.

There are such enumerations { first, second} and properties health, step, position . If you select the first, then display the name and step in the Editor, if the second, the step and position . I figured out how to do this for the monobehavior class. And how to do this so that the array has dynamic properties for each element of the array?The image highlights the fields I would like to see when I select this list . Thanks in advance . Sorry my bad english

[image]

Comment: My question is different, there is specified as soon as for the monobehavior class not serialized hide properties, and I have for the array (which consists of a serialized class)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52859550/edit) your question to include your `CustomEditor` code in `MyClass`

Comment: I'ld recommend you use `ReorderableList` for something like that. It is a bit tricky at the beginning but once you got it it makes things very clean and structured + Adding, removing etc is covered by SerializedProperties so Undo/redo and marking as dirty is all handled for you. Here is a [tutorial](http://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist/) I followed once and found it great.

Comment: "Please edit your question to include your CustomEditor code in MyClass" -  unfortunately now the code is not working(used serializedproperty in customeditor), if it works, I will share the answer necessarily                          "I'ld recommend you use ReorderableList for something like that. It is a bit tricky at the beginning but once you got it it makes things very clean and structured + Adding, removing etc is covered by SerializedProperties so Undo/redo and marking as dirty is all handled for you. Here is a tutorial I followed once and found it great" - I will try,thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example using `ReaorderableList` from `UnityEditorInternal` (I basically learned it using [this cool turorial](http://va.lent.in/unity-make-your-lists-functional-with-reorderablelist)) which I find way more flexible and clean than directly doing everything on `OnInspectorGUI`.

And an additional feature is as the name says: The elements can be selected and made reorderable using drag+drop!

**The List element's class**

```c#
[Serializeable]
puclic class YourClass
{
    public enum YourEnum
    {
        first,
        second
    }

    public YourEnum Enum;
    public string Name;
    public int Step;
    public Vector3 Position;
}
```

**The class containing the list**

```c#
public class YourOtherClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<YourClass> YourList = new List<YourClass>();

    // It works the same for arrays if you prefere that, no need to change the inspector
    // Note that in this case you can't initalize it here yet but the Inspector does that for you
    // public YourClass[] YourList ;
}
```

**Editor**

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(YourOtherClass))]
public class YourOtherClassEditor : Editor
{
    // This will be the serialized "copy" of YourOtherClass.YourList
    private SerializedProperty YourList;


    private ReorderableList YourReorderableList;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Step 1 "link" the SerializedProperties to the properties of YourOtherClass
        YourList = serializedObject.FindProperty("YourList");

        // Step 2 setup the ReorderableList
        YourReorderableList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, YourList)
        {
            // Can your objects be dragged an their positions changed within the List?
            draggable = true,

            // Can you add elements by pressing the "+" button?
            displayAdd = true,

            // Can you remove Elements by pressing the "-" button?
            displayRemove = true,

            // Make a header for the list
            drawHeaderCallback = rect =>
            {
                EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "This are your Elements");
            },

            // Now to the interesting part: Here you setup how elements look like
            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, active, focused) =>
            {
                // Get the currently to be drawn element from YourList
                var element = YourList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                // Get the elements Properties into SerializedProperties
                var Enum = element.FindPropertyRelative("Enum");
                var Name = element.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var Step = element.FindPropertyRelative("Step");
                var Position = element.FindPropertyRelative("Position");

                // Draw the Enum field
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), Enum);
                // start the next property in the next line
                rect.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                // only show Name field if selected "first"
                if ((YourClass.YourEnum)Enum.intValue == YourClass.YourEnum.first)
                {
                    EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), Name);
                    // start the next property in the next line
                    rect.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                }

                // Draw the Step field
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), Step);
                // start the next property in the next line
                rect.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                // only show Step field if selected "seconds"
                if ((YourClass.YourEnum)Enum.intValue == YourClass.YourEnum.second)
                {
                    EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), Position);
                }
            },

            // And since we have more than one line (default) you'll have to configure 
            // how tall your elements are. Luckyly in your example it will always be exactly
            // 3 Lines in each case. If not you would have to change this.
            // In some cases it becomes also more readable if you use one more Line as spacer between the elements
            elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 3,

            //alternatively if you have different heights you would use e.g.
            //elementHeightCallback = index =>
            //{
            //    var element = YourList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
            //    var Enum = element.FindPropertyRelative("Enum");

            //    switch ((YourClass.YourEnum)Enum.intValue)
            //    {
            //        case YourClass.YourEnum.first:
            //            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 3;

            //        case YourClass.YourEnum.second:
            //            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 5;

            //            default:
            //                return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            //    }
            //}

            // optional: Set default Values when adding a new element
            // (otherwise the values of the last list item will be copied)
            onAddCallback = list =>
            {
                // The new index will be the current List size ()before adding
                var index = list.serializedProperty.arraySize;

                // Since this method overwrites the usual adding, we have to do it manually:
                // Simply counting up the array size will automatically add an element
                list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                list.index = index;
                var element = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

                // again link the properties of the element in SerializedProperties
                var Enum = element.FindPropertyRelative("Enum");
                var Name = element.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var Step = element.FindPropertyRelative("Step");
                var Position = element.FindPropertyRelative("Position");

                // and set default values
                Enum.intValue = (int) YourClass.YourEnum.first;
                Name.stringValue = "";
                Step.intValue = 0;
                Position.vector3Value = Vector3.zero;
            }
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // copy the values of the real Class to the linked SerializedProperties
        serializedObject.Update();

        // print the reorderable list
        YourReorderableList.DoLayoutList();

        // apply the changed SerializedProperties values to the real class
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

don't forget to use

```c#
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `MyClass` is defined like this:

```c#
public class MyClass {
    public enum MyEnumType {first, second} ;
    public MyEnumType enumNumber;
    public String name;
    public int step;
    public Vector3 position; 
}
```

There are three steps:

### 1. Create a custom List wrapper `MyCustomList`

```c#
// Script name : MyCustomList.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; // Import the System.Collections.Generic class to give us access to List<>

public class MyCustomList: MonoBehaviour { 
    //This is our list we want to use to represent our class as an array.
    public List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>(1);
}
```

### 2. CustomEditor for the wrapper: `MyCustomListEditor`

```c#
// Script name : MyCustomListEditor.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyCustomList))]

public class MyCustomListEditor : Editor {
    MyCustomList t;
    SerializedObject GetTarget;
    SerializedProperty ThisList;
    int ListSize;

    void OnEnable(){
        t = (MyCustomList)target;
        GetTarget = new SerializedObject(t);
        ThisList = GetTarget.FindProperty("MyList"); // Find the List in our script and create a reference of it
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI(){
        //Update our list

        GetTarget.Update();

        //Resize our list
        EditorGUILayout.Space ();
        EditorGUILayout.Space ();
        ListSize = ThisList.arraySize;
        ListSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField ("List Size", ListSize);

        if(ListSize != ThisList.arraySize){
            while(ListSize > ThisList.arraySize){
                ThisList.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(ThisList.arraySize);
            }
            while(ListSize < ThisList.arraySize){
                ThisList.DeleteArrayElementAtIndex(ThisList.arraySize - 1);
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.Space ();
        EditorGUILayout.Space ();

        //Display our list to the inspector window

        for(int i = 0; i < ThisList.arraySize; i++){
            SerializedProperty MyListRef = ThisList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            SerializedProperty MyEnum= MyListRef.FindPropertyRelative("enumName");
            SerializedProperty MyName = MyListRef.FindPropertyRelative("name");
            SerializedProperty MyStep = MyListRef.FindPropertyRelative("step");
            SerializedProperty MyPosition = MyListRef.FindPropertyRelative("position");


            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(MyEnum);

            int MyEnumIndex = MyEnum.enumValueIndex;

            // Show/hide the properties based on the index of the enumValue. 
            if (MyEnumIndex == (int)MyClass.MyEnumType.first) {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(MyName);
            } 

            if (MyEnumIndex == (int)MyClass.MyEnumType.second) {
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(MyPosition);
            }

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(MyStep);

            EditorGUILayout.Space ();

            //Remove this index from the List
            if(GUILayout.Button("Remove This Index (" + i.ToString() + ")")){
                ThisList.DeleteArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            }
            EditorGUILayout.Space ();
            EditorGUILayout.Space ();
            EditorGUILayout.Space ();
            EditorGUILayout.Space ();
        }

        //Apply the changes to our list
        GetTarget.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

### 3. Change `BigClass` to use `MyCustomList` instead of `List<MyClass>`

```c#
public class BigClass : MonoBehaviour {
    MyCustomList myList = new MyCustomList();

    // .. Whatever else is in BigClass

}
```

This is adopted from [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/display-a-list-class-with-a-custom-editor-script.227847/) on the Unity forums.

Comment: Note that it can lead to issues mixing SerializedProperties with direct manipulations of the original target (`AddNew` and `Remove`). Since for those you will not have Redo/Undo support

Comment: Good point. I can't seem to find where they are used in the custom script. I'm just going to remove them unless someone notices they are useful in some way.

Comment: Yep sorry my fault as well. I thought this would be used in the inspector through the `t` from `t = (MyCustomList)target;`. You don't need this actually since you never use it -> and you never should unless in some special cases

Comment: So to be clear, now that they are removed, this answer doesn't have an undo/redo problem? I like yours better, personally, but might as well document this alternative if it's worthwhile.

Comment: Nope since you are only setting things through SerializedProperties they handle that. But I don't really understand your Step 3, though .. what is that for?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @derHugo just that you need to use the wrapper in whatever `BigClass` has the `MyClass` collection so unity can render that part of `BigClass` among all the other parts of `BigClass`.  I just realized I was using `MyClass` incorrectly so I edited my question to correct that.

Comment: But than `MyCustomList` should also be a normal class and not inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. In general you would than rather implement a `CustomPropertyDrawer` instead of `Editor`.