# Can i make a dropdown in the component of a script? - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making an script, and i want to make a dropdown that if is an option, show some variables.
Like in RigidBody 2D:
Body Type: if is in "Dynamic" show an amount of variables to set, but if is in "Kinematic" show other amount of variables to set.

Any ideas to do it?

I answer any question.

I tried to found in Google, Youtube but i didn't found anything about it.

Comment: This is done by implementing a [`Custom Inspector`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-HowTo-CreateCustomInspector.html) for your component .. or [`Custom PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html) for a `[Serializable]` class ... here is one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74037328/how-to-hide-a-variable-depending-on-the-value-of-another-variable-without-monobe .. here another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859550/display-certain-properties-of-array-members-in-unity-editor-depending-on-other-p

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a custom inspector or use an enum

```
public enum Shape
{
    Circle,
    Square,
    Triangle
}
```

and add a field into a MonoBehaviour

```
public Shape shape;
```

Will look like that

[image]

### And the hard and long way

```
EditorGUILayout.Popup(indexOfTheSelectedOption, stringArrayOfOptions);
```

Here's an example

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScript))]
public class MyScriptEditor : Editor
{        
    // the index of selected option
    private int index;

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // the index of selected option
        index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(index, new string[] { "Option1", "etc" });
    }
}
```

You can find more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html).

Edited:

As you asked in the comments

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScript))]
public class MyScriptEditor : Editor
{        
    // the serialized fields of the varibles you wanna change
    SerialiedProperty var1, var2, var3; // ...etc.

    // the index of selected option
    private int index;


    private void Awake()
    {
        var1 = serializedObject.FindProperty("var1");
        var2 = serializedObject.FindProperty("var2");
        var3 = serializedObject.FindProperty("var2"); // the string is the name of your field
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // the index of selected option
        index = EditorGUILayout.Popup(index, new string[] { "Option1", "etc" });

        object yourVal;

        switch (index)
        {
        case 0:
            yourVal = EditorGUILayout.FloatField(yourVal);
            break;
        /*
            and etc,
            you create the field in inspector you want for eevery index

            but tbh, that's a bad idea to do so
        */
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but how can i make it show vars if it is in "Circle" option and other vars if it is in "Square" option?

Comment: Literally variables? So you can choose what variable to change?

Comment: Anyway, I edited the code so you can see how to do it, but I've given you enough info to learn things by yourself, use Unity Docs man